# Need to batch INSERT with foreign key

Tags: sql, relational-database, cockroachdb

I am currently using CockroachDB and need to batch insert store category code.

Here is my current table schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE storecategorycode(
  id                        UUID            PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  isenabled                 BOOLEAN         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE storecategorycodeml(
  id                        UUID            PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 
  gen_random_uuid(),
  storecategorycode_id      UUID            NOT NULL,
  category1                 VARCHAR(255)    NULL,
  category2                 VARCHAR(255)    NULL,
  category3                 VARCHAR(255)    NULL,
  category4                 VARCHAR(255)    NULL,
  category5                 VARCHAR(255)    NULL,
  lang                      VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT storecategorycodeml_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (storecategorycode_id)   
    REFERENCES storecategorycode(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

storecategorycodeml ('ml' stands for 'multi-language') depends on storecategorycode_id foreign key.

How do I insert something like this?

```sql
INSERT INTO storecategorycodeml 
(storecategorycode_id, category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, lang) 
VALUES (
  INSERT INTO storecategorycode(isenabled) VALUES(true) 
  RETURNING id,'Restaurant','Restaurant-1','Cafe','In-store','takeout','en'
);
```

'RETURNING id' is a syntax used in cockroachDB to return inserted id.

I can create a script to manually first create a record in storecategorycode and create record in storecategorycodeml but **I will be inserting thousands of records** and I prefer not to manually code these.

FYI, the reason why I have separate table is to support multi-language.  For example, I can have a storecategorycode( 001, true) and the 001 can have multiple languages such as in English, Korean, Chinese, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if your DBMS supports this chained `INSERT` syntax, but it's worth a shot:

```sql
WITH inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO storecategorycode(isenabled) VALUES(true) 
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO storecategorycodeml 
(storecategorycode_id, category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, lang) 
SELECT id, 'Restaurant','Restaurant-1','Cafe','In-store','takeout','en'
FROM inserted
;
```

This will do the `INSERT` into `storecategorycode` first, then return the `id` value and let you reference it in the subsequent `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this. I need to insert about 5000 store category codes.  Does this mean I need to write the above query 5000 times?  I do understand I can probably write a python script to loop these but was wondering if there is a way to do. INSERT () VALUES (), (), () .... ();

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not sure how CockroachDB works, but in other DBs (i.e. Postgres) you can do it with multiple rows.  Give it a try and see :)